Apache Camel 4.4 SFTP health check probe failed
I have a route (removing all the extra options to simplify) of
from("sftp://servername:22?username=username&password=password&preferredAuthentications=password)

pom.xml dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-ftp-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

It used to work in Camel 2.x, but in Camel 4.4 (Red Hat Camel 4.4 build specifically) I'm getting:

Probe in group 'camel', with id 'consumer:route3' failed with message 'Consumer has not yet polled route


Can you please include the whole RouteBuilder code?
